# How can I set data-row value in javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this line in jQuery and I want to `set row=(that)` in my code value to changed. When edited on that.

```
<tr data-state="unChanged">
$(that).data('state').value = "changed";
```

I get assignment left side error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(that).data("state","changed");
```

I have fixed with this line...

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(that).attr('data-state', 'changed'); // jQuery

var tdEelem = document.getElementById('someId');  // Javascript
tdEelem.setAttribute('data-stat' , 'changed');
```

Comment: Also good to note that jQuery's `.data()` method can only be used to modify the jQuery object — it does not write into the DOM (i.e. modify HTML5 `data-` attributes).

Comment: I have try with Jquery . It doesn't change attribute . I can read this value . I am on right that . have checked . I cannot change.